# How to create animated gif in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, gif, animated-gif

How can I create animated gif from multiple jpeg-s in ASP.NET Core?

I prefer library that is not attach to windows environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should try using Magick.Net which is a good image manipulation library and is also available for .net core.  An example of how to create a .gif can be found [here](https://magick.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Combining%20images&referringTitle=Documentation).

To add Magick.Net to your .net core project you'll need to modify your project.json as follows:

```
"dependencies":
{
   "Magick.NET.Core-Q8": "7.0.0.0102"
}
```

Hope this helps!